# Smart way of counting sequences of 1s and 0s (Markov chain)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Assume a sequence (`np.array`) of 1s and 0s. I need to construct 2-nd order Markov chain. For that, I need to count to proportion of T001, ... T111, where T001 is the number of times the sequences had a [0,0,1] occuring. Obviously I could do a for loop, but I am trying to avoid that. Ideally, the method could be extended to k-oder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`more_itertools.windowed`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#windowing) and [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/collections.html):

```
from more_itertools import windowed
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.choice([0,1], size=100)

Counter(windowed(a, n=3))
```

input:

```
array([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,
       1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0])
```

output:

```
Counter({(0, 1, 1): 14,
         (1, 1, 0): 14,
         (1, 0, 1): 15,
         (1, 1, 1): 16,
         (1, 0, 0): 10,
         (0, 0, 1): 10,
         (0, 1, 0): 12,
         (0, 0, 0): 7})
```

With custom keys:

```
{'T'+''.join(map(str, k)): v for k,v in Counter(windowed(a, n=3)).items()}
```

output:

```
{'T011': 14,
 'T110': 14,
 'T101': 15,
 'T111': 16,
 'T100': 10,
 'T001': 10,
 'T010': 12,
 'T000': 7}
```

#### How to ensure all values are present (even if zero count):

##### easy solution: generate a list of all possible keys and use this to iterate

```
from itertools import product
possible_keys = ['T'+''.join(map(str, k)) for k in product([0,1], repeat=3)]
```

output:

```
['T000', 'T001', 'T010', 'T011', 'T100', 'T101', 'T110', 'T111']
```

The you can combine with the use of the dictionary `get` method:

```
## as comprehension
{k: out.get(k, 0) for k in possible_keys}

## as classical loop
for key in possible_keys:
    out.get(key, 0) # default value is 0
```

###### full example:

```
from itertools import product
a = [0,1,1,0]
out = {'T'+''.join(map(str, k)): v for k,v in Counter(windowed(a, n=3)).items()}
possible_keys = ['T'+''.join(map(str, k)) for k in product([0,1], repeat=3)]
out = {k: out.get(k, 0) for k in possible_keys}
```

output:

```
{'T000': 0,
 'T001': 0,
 'T010': 0,
 'T011': 1,
 'T100': 0,
 'T101': 0,
 'T110': 1,
 'T111': 0}
```

##### dictionary updating (python ≥3.9)

```
from itertools import product
default = {'T'+''.join(map(str, k)): 0 for k in product([0,1], repeat=3)}
out = default | out # update default with the values in out
```

Comment: This doesn't output however Txxx = 0 if Txx was not in the sequence.

Comment: @deblue you can use a defaultdict: `from collections import defaultdict ; out = defaultdict(int, {'T'+''.join(map(str, k)): v for k,v in Counter(windowed(a, n=3)).items()}) ; out['Txxx']`

Comment: There are other ways if you want a dictionary with all values, let me know what you exactly need and I'll update the answer

Comment: Hi, thanks, but this is also not useful for me since I need to create proportions, as such: `{'p'+''.join(map(str, k[1:])): v for k,v in zip(d.keys(), np.array(list(d.values())) / sum(list(d.values())))}`. Well, ideally, since the order is 2 (meaning 3 occurances in a sequence), I would need a 4x4 matrix with Txxx's, which would then allow me to divide by the sum and get the proportions.

Comment: @deblue I added a few example to ensure the output has all keys, there are many other ways, let me know is this worked for you ;)

Comment: NB. your `'p'+''.join(map(str, k[1:]))` could be just `'p'+k[1:]` ;)

Answer (score 4):

The task can be split into two subtasks: First is creating all the subsequences of length 3, then counting all the unique subsequences. Both these tasks can be done with built in `numpy` methods:

Assuming the input sequence is stored as a numpy array in `a`, the first point can be achieved with

```
windows = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(a, 3)
```

Then we can count the distinct windows using

```
unique_windows, counts = np.unique(windows, axis=0, return_counts=True)
```